# Why cypress fails to identify if we give full class name

Tags: css-selectors, jquery-selectors, cypress

If I am giving the full class name for example: `title-text-panel-container class-about-benefits > ul` cypress fails to identify the element and throws below error 
C*ypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.title-text-panel-container class-about-benefits > ul', but never found it*.
Why cypress fails to identify if we give `full class name` in the test ? But it passes the test as we give the class name as per Test 2.

**Test 1:** **Fails**

```
cy.get('.title-text-panel-container class-about-benefits > ul').find('li').its('length').should('be.gte', 1);
```

**Test: 2 Passes**

```
cy.get('.title-text-panel-container > ul').find('li').its('length').should('be.gte', 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try it with a '.' before the second class, `cy.get('.title-text-panel-container .class-about-benefits > ul')`

Comment: I always use the longer form `cy.get('[class^=something]')` - means the class list starts with 'something', or `cy.get('[class*=something]')` - means the class list contains 'something'.

Comment: I didn't try with `.` before the second class, I thought it was considered as a single class. Anyway thanks for explaining that. Second or third option is more easy shorter version `cy.get('[class^=something]')` or `cy.get('[class*=something]')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.classA .classB` selector implies `classB` to be descendant of `classA`. If you want to specify multiple classes of a single DOM element (to increase specificity), you must not add a space between them: `.classA.classB`.

In your case, it'd be:

```
cy.get('.title-text-panel-container.class-about-benefits > ul').find('li').its('length').should('be.gte', 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 
    `cy.get('.title-text-panel-container .class-about-benefits > ul')`

Comment: Eric99 has already provided the answer in his comments above. Thanks anway, awesome help.

Comment: This is incorrect selector hierarchy; see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578194/927631)